# How to Publish on my facebook page from my facebook app?

Tags: facebook, publish

I want to publish images to my facebook page from my application/website. How can I do this? Can anyone help me out with a php code?

Comment: This is way too broad. What app? What issue are you having? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Feed** API

eg: from javascript you can do like this-

```
var obj =   {
                link: URL,
                message: MESSAGE,
                access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,

            };

FB.api('/PAGE_ID/feed', 'post',obj);
```

Note- the ACCESS_TOKEN is the user's token for the APP.

In this way the feed will be published on PAGE through the APP